# getting a list after grouping in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table Food. It has fields: `cust_name, phone_number , order_date`

I am trying to build a dictionary where a key of pair (cust_name, phone_number) gives a list of order_date. For that I need to query appropriately in `sqlalchemy`. I'm using Postgres.

So far I have:

```
db.session.query(Food.cust_name, Food.phone_number).group_by(Food.cust_name, Food.phone_number).all()
```

What do I need to change so that I get a corresponding list of `order_date`

Comment: That depends on your DB in use, so please include that information.

Comment: I have edited it. I'm using postgres FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) aggregate function to produce a list of order dates:

```
res = db.session.query(Food.cust_name,
                       Food.phone_number,
                       db.func.array_agg(Food.order_date).label('order_dates')).\
    group_by(Food.cust_name, Food.phone_number).\
    all()

the_dict = {(r.cust_name, r.phone_number): r.order_dates for r in res}
```